# Could not retrieve information from environment production source

Tags: vagrant, puppet, provisioning, vagrantfile

I'm using puppet as my provisioner in one of my vagrant project. I'm trying to add a module for a custom bash_profile.

The `module_path` for puppet is set to:

```
 puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
```

The class for my bash_profile module looks like this:

```
class bash_profile
{
    file
    {
        "/home/vagrant/bash_profile":
            ensure => present,
            source => "puppet:///modules/bash_profile/files/bash_profile"
    }
}
```

Here's the file structure for my puppet structure:

```
puppet
| manifests
| | phpbase.pp // my main manifest file that has includes for modules
| modules
| | bash_profile
| | | files
| | | | bash_profile // the actual bash_profile file I want to ensure is present on my VM
| | | manifests
| | | | init.pp // the init file included for the bash_profile class
```

When I run the provisioning for vagrant, I get the error

> err: /Stage[main]/Bash_profile/File[/home/vagrant/bash_profile]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/bash_profile/files/bash_profile at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0/bash_profile/manifests/init.pp:8

I'm not sure why it can't retrieve the information. The path seems to be correct. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: @timbooo, just curious, why did you edit the title? I prefix my questions that way so it's easier for me to look back through them later.

Comment: It's not necessary to put tags into the title, see [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). Tags could be used by you as well to go through your questions in a topic-related manner.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the link and clarification.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you are not supposed to include the literal `files/` in the URL. Instead, it should just be

```
puppet:///modules/bash_profile/bash_profile
```

Comment: I just read the same documentation and missed the same point. Four hours trying to get that URL straight! I also tried using file URI's. My colleague said that in the source attribute you need to leave the "file:" off. Not sure about that, but it works for him.

Comment: Geez, that definitely flies in the face of what I expect from paths.

Answer (score 1):

You may also receive this error with `recurse => true` if your module name is invalid. For instance, if you have this module structure:

`modules
├── my-example
│   └── files
│       └── example
│           └── test.txt`

and this resource:

```
file { "/tmp/example":
  ensure => directory,
  recurse => true,
  source => "puppet:///modules/my-example/example",
}
```

you'll get this error:

`==> default: Info: Could not find filesystem info for file 'my-example/example' in environment production
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/File[/tmp/example]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///my-example/example`

The fix is to rename the module—for instance, naming it `my_example` fixes it. The [rules for module names are documented](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/modules_fundamentals.html#allowed-module-names) but easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Things to care about

1. The Puppet URI format `puppet:///modules/name_of_module/filename`
2. The fileserver directory to be present in the module directory

This [video](https://goo.gl/C9DeLb) is an shows step-by-step guide to resolve the error